What is the most explicit form of Differential Equation?
I'm trying tu understand the definition of a differential equation:
$$G(t, y(t), \dots, y^{(n)}(t)) = 0$$
What I understand is that:

G is a function
t is the independent variable
y(t) is a function that determines a dependent variable
$y^{(n)}(t)$ is the nth derivative of the same function

Questions
Do this mean parameters of $G$ are operands that and can be operated in any form?
$$2x^2+2^{x+4}-\  \sin^{-1}(\ln(x+2))$$
Could be more than one independent variable? If yes, why is not specified?
$$t_1,t_2,t_3...$$
Do $y(t)$ determine the value of a single dependent variable or more?
$$y(t) = 2t \implies y = 2t$$
Could be more than one dependent variable? If yes, why is not specified?
$$y(t),x(t),z(t),...$$
Could dependent variables depend on the independent value and other dependent variables?
$$y(t) = 2tx$$
Based on my own questions I think this definition is correct because shows progression in 3 different dimensions while the original shows just in a single dimension witch is the derivative index:
$$G(t_1,f^{(0)}(t_1),g^{(0)}(t_1),...,h^{(0)}(t_1),f^{(1)}(t_1),g^{(1)}(t_1),...,h^{(1)}(t_1),...,f^{(n)}(t_1),g^{(n)}(t_1),...,h^{(n)}(t_1)),\\ t_2,f^{(0)}(t_2),g^{(0)}(t_2),...,h^{(0)}(t_2),f^{(1)}(t_2),g^{(1)}(t_2),...,h^{(1)}(t_2),...,f^{(n)}(t_2),g^{(n)}(t_2),...,h^{(n)}(t_2)),...t_m,f^{(0)}(t_m),g^{(0)}(t_m),...,h^{(0)}(t_m),f^{(1)}(t_m),g^{(1)}(t_m),...,h^{(1)}(t_m),...,f^{(n)}(t_m),g^{(n)}(t_m),...,h^{(n)}(t_m))$$
I suppose it is not correct or too much explicit. Please explain me more in deep.

Unclear which of several definitions at the link you are referring to.  The first definition in the Question permits multiple dependent variables and multiple independent variables.  The Answers seem to restrict to ordinary differential equations (where there is exactly one independent variable) having one dependent variable (the function for which we ostensibly intend to solve).
